# How can I set retention policy for logs exported from Elastic beanstalk into a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, retention

I am using elastic beanstalk to serve up our app. I have enabled the "Enable log file rotation to Amazon S3" option and I see the logs a writing to a bucket. It looks like the logs are going to the default bucket for the Elastic BeanStalk instance.

1. How can I tell the app to write logs to a different bucket?
2. I want to make sure we set a retention policy (say 10 days) for the logs in that bucket so that the bucket stays groomed.

Thank you in advance for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not possible to configure the Elastic Beanstalk app to publish logs to a different bucket. It can only be set off or on.
2. To delete logs after 10 days, you can add a lifecycle rule to your bucket that will delete the logs after 10 days: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/lifecycle-configuration-bucket-no-versioning.html

However, it may also possible to configure your Elastic Beanstalk application to publish logs to CloudWatch logs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.cw.html

The docs show a console screenshot, but I don't see anywhere in the console to set this. The docs do reference settings you can set via configuration files, CLI, or SDK